# Adding action in component in CakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp, datatable, components

I'm trying to create a CakePHP component for JQuery datatables in server-side mode. I've got the datatable working but I want to componentize it so I can reuse it in multiple controllers.

When I include my new component in a controller I want it to create a new action on that controller called tabledata to handle the XHR queries from JQuery. Is such a thing possible?

I'd also like to know if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way.

Comment: I'd start here, http://book.cakephp.org/view/64/Creating-Components

Comment: I'm OK with creating a component. My specific problem is adding a new action from the component.

Comment: Yeah good question.  I'd also like to use Components to be able to create controller actions, but I'm not sure if there's a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a __call() method in your app_controller to test if your component loaded and then do something.